# Return empty string if the capture group doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Applying the regular expression `.*/(?<X>.*?(?<Rev>\#rev#.*?))\$(?<YM>\d{6})\.` to the following strings

```
    /ABC$201808.csv
    /ABC#Rev#123$201808.csv
```

only matches and captures the second string

```
    /ABC#Rev#123$201808. has 3 groups:
      ABC#Rev#123 (X)
      #Rev#123 (Rev)
      201808 (YM)
```

For the first string of `/ABC$201808.csv`, I want to capture the following values (`Rev` should get empty string).

```
      ABC(X)
      (Rev)
      201808 (YM)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing a `?` in your regular expression after the `<Rev>` grouping. It should be `.*/(?<X>.*?(?<Rev>\#rev#.*?)?)\$(?<YM>\d{6})\.` in order to match both strings.